# Selecting Selected line in listbox python tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, listbox, tkinter

Hi i have a question to ask regarding Python Tkinter Listbox. when i select the value, what must i add into my code so that the Listbox would return the value? There is no need for multiple selection. Or, can i add in a button to execute a command, while putting the returned value from the listbox into the command? I am using Python 2.7 and lis is the name of my array. Thank you for your kind attention and help!

```
master = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.pack()

listbox.insert(END, "Please select:")

for p in lis:
    listbox.insert(END, p)

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can add button to check selection

```
from Tkinter import *

def check_list():
    try:
        s = lb.selection_get()
        print 'selected:', s
    except:
        print 'no selection'

master = Tk()

lb = Listbox(master)
lb.pack()

lb.insert(END, "Please select:")
for p in range(10):
    lb.insert(END, p)

but = Button(master, text="Check", command=check_list)
but.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

---

if you need some argument in `command` then use `lambda`

```
command=lambda:my_function(argument)
```

BTW: look out on argument in `command=` when you use it in `for` loop

This puts value `10` in place of `i` in all `my_function(i)`

```
for i in range(10):
     ... command=lambda:my_function(i)
```

This works as expected

```
for i in range(10):
     ... command=lambda x=i:my_function(x)
```

---

**EDIT:**

`lb.selection_get()` gives text from listbox (and use `\n` to seperate elements in multiselection) and raise error if there is no selection.

`lb.curselection()` gives list of indexes and empty list if there is no selection.

```
def check_list_2():
    s = lb.curselection()
    if not s:
        print 'no selection'
    else:
        for x in s:
            print 'selected index:', x
            print 'selected text:', lb.get(x)
```

Comment: Exactly the thing i was finding for. Thanks so much!

Comment: Add `master.destroy()`  after `print 'no selection'` and window will close too.

Comment: @Alper I don't want to close it

Comment: @furas I am using this as a selection box from a multiple choice. After selected, I want it to be closed and return the value to me. That is why I wrote it down so if anyone wonders the same thing.

Comment: @Alper OP didn't say if he/she want to close it and this wasn't main problem in question. I normally use more complex GUI and I put selected element in other widget or I use it to  run function and put result in other widget - and all this need to run tkinter all time. Different person need use selected value in different way.

Comment: @Alper  BTW: but if you need to use selected value after closing GUI then you need also assign value to global variable - to access it outside function `check_list`. On Stackoverflow there was similar question - how to get this value after closing `tkitner`